# Is Set coclosed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories

Background: $\mathbf{Set}$ is a (cartesian) closed monoidal category, so we have the natural tensor-hom adjunction $\text{Hom}(X\times Y,Z)\cong\text{Hom}(X,\text{Hom}(Y,Z))$ for sets $X,Y,Z$.

Apparently, $\mathbf{Ab}$ is a "coclosed" category, i.e. there is an abelian group $\text{cohom}(A,B)$ such that $\text{hom}(\text{cohom}(A,B),C)\cong\text{hom}(A,B\times C)$ for abelian groups $A,B,C$.

I'm wondering whether $\mathbf{Set}$ is coclosed as well. Concretely, my questions are:

1. Is there a set, say $\text{Cohom}(X,Y)$, such that we have a natural isomorphism ("cohom-tensor-adjunction") $\text{Hom}(\text{Cohom}(X,Y),Z)\cong\text{Hom}(X,Y\times Z)$? How is it constructed?
2. Does $\text{Coend}(X):=\text{Cohom}(X,X)$ have any special properties? By duality, it should be a comonoid. Is the comultiplication different from the diagonal map?
3. Does the cohom-tensor-adjunction restrict to an isomorphism between "corepresentations" of $C$ and (right) $C$-comodules for a comonoid $C$? By a corepresentation of $C$, I mean a comonoid morphism $\text{Coend}(X)\to C$ for some set $X$.
4. There is a restricted naturality statement between $M$-linear isomorphisms and isomorphisms of representations of $M$ given by conjugation for a monoid $M$. Is there an analogue in the dualized setting? I.e. is there a naturality statement between some isomorphisms of corepresentations of $C$ and $C$-colinear isomorphisms for a comonoid $C$?

(If the construction of $\text{Cohom}(X,Y)$ is easy, I can probably figure out questions 2.-4. on my own.)

Comment: if $Z=\{*\}$ is the terminal object, then $Hom(Cohom(X,Y),Z)=\{*\}$ whereas $Hom(X,Y\times Z)=Hom(X,Y)$. This implies that you cannot expect the existence of $Cohom(X,Y)$ in general.

Comment: So if $\text{Cohom}(X,Y)$ exists, we have $\text{Hom}(X,Y)=\{*\}$, hence $X=\emptyset$ or $Y=\{*\}$. In the first case, we have $\text{Cohom}(\emptyset,Y)=\emptyset$. In the second case, we have $\text{Cohom}(X,\{*\})\cong X$ by the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: in order for an adjoint to *all* $B\times -$ to exist, each of those functors has to preserve limits; in particular, it has to preserve the terminal object, and it doesn't if $B$ has more than two elements. So, the largest subcategory of $\bf Set$ where a left adjoint to $B\times-$ exists is the one made of singletons... Not an interesting category!